# I would like to know that whether or not data binded to the repeater in item template

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

Here I am providing my source code for better understanding

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPatientServices" runat="server" DataSourceID="PatientServicesDataSource">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <span class="folders" year="<%#Eval("Year") %>" payer="<%#Eval("Initials") %>" month="<%#Eval("Month") %>" name="<%#Eval("Patientname") %>"  
      firstday="<%#Eval("FirstDay") %>" lastday="<%#Eval("LastDay") %>" >
    </span>

   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

I want to know whether the firstday, lastday are loaded or not ? without going anywhere, I would like to know here itself, I mean in the Itemtemplate only, I was tried with alert like `alert("<%#Eval("FirstDay") %>")` something like that, but it wont be worked out, please any one help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by "know"? Are you trying to debug something? The fact that data is being displayed (or not) should be confirmation enough, right?

Comment: Repeater itself will show data in browser. What else you are expecting

Comment: it is showing undefined for the firstday and lastday fields to me and remaining are loaded perfectly

Comment: It means you are getting null field from database. How you are binding data to repeater

Comment: Try like this ` firstday='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FirstDay")`

Answer (score 0):

@Prince can you please check the data you are binding to the reapeter. I think you are getting null values for the Date fields.

You can use the firebug or the google developer tool for checking your code in the browser.

Comment: Repeater itself will show data in browser. Why to go for firebug or developer tool

Comment: @Rahul I am appreciating your answer, but if the span is hide by other controls or case it is not be view by the user client side tools may save a lot time.

Comment: No, I do have 3 records in the database @Nivas

Comment: @Prince do the 'firstday' and 'lastday' have values that are not null?